# How to stop Python rewriting files?

Tags: python, file, text

Is there a way to stop Python rewriting files?

For example, when I run code once, it writes number "1" in text file. If I run same code tommorow, it won't erase that 1 from yesterday, it will add one more "1", so it should look like this:

> 1
>
> 1

My would look like this:

```
file = open("filename","w")
file.write(str(1) + "\n)
file.close()
```

If someone can tell me where is my mistake, please help me.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please add your code.. For more info on asking a good question, go to the [help] and read [ask]. Also, it is unclear what you want: do you want to keep adding to the existing file or start fresh each day?

Comment: As I said, keep adding into the same file. :/

Comment: Look at [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in the docs. That table of *mode* values is probably what you're looking for. (And this is useful to learn, because it's closely related to what C does, and therefore what a whole lot of other languages do.)

Comment: abarnert I looked in docs and i saw this:
'a' open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
So, I think this is something I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the docs for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), that second parameter that you're passing a `"w"` to is the `mode`:

> *mode* is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to `'r'` which means open for reading in text mode. Other common values are `'w'` for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), `'x'` for exclusive creation and `'a'` for appending…

And then there's a handy chart of all of the mode characters, which reiterates the same information:

- `'w'`: open for writing, truncating the file first
- ...
- `'a'`: open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

So, just use `"a"` instead of `"w"`, and Python will add your new line to the end of the file, instead of truncating the file to nothing and then adding your new line to that now-empty file.

---

It's probably worth knowing that this is very closely based on the behavior of the [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html) function from C and POSIX—which many other languages have also copied. So, in almost any language you run into, if there's a `w` mode for writing that overwrites the file, there's probably also an `a` mode for appending.